# Log4net clearing session variable

Tags: vb.net, session, log4net

I have an web app where I am trying to implement log4net. The job is to write the page name user requests. Here's my code:

**Global.asax.vb**

```
Sub Application_AcquireRequestState(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires upon attempting to authenticate the use
    If InStr(Request.FilePath, ".aspx") > 0 Then
        Logger.WriteDebug(Request.FilePath)
    End If

End Sub
```

**Logger class:**

```
Imports log4net    
Public NotInheritable Class Logger
Private Shared log As log4net.ILog
Public Shared Sub InitializeLogger()
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()
    log = LogManager.GetLogger("Testlogger")
End Sub
Public Shared Sub WriteDebug(ByVal Message As String)
    If (log Is Nothing) Then
        InitializeLogger()
    End If

    log.Debug(Message)
End Sub
End Class
```

Also the log4net.config file where the configuration is written. The log is writing perfectly in my file but the problem is after writing a single log somehow the **Session** variable is cleared/wiped out. So, I have to login again to my app, again the session variable is cleared.

If I comment out

> log.Debug(Message)

only this line everything works perfectly. I have debugged this for a long time, no error occurs nothing but that piece of line resetting my Session variable.

As I have experience of implementing log4net in other apps, I think the problem is not of log4net. Any ideas what can be the issue?

Comment: Where is your log file getting written?   If it's going to the /bin folder, any file changes to this folder should recycle the application - killing your sessions.

Comment: Yes, I am writing in the bin folder will change the folder and try it now!

Comment: @onskee Yes! That was the issue, changed the log file folder and it's working just fine. Thanks! You saved my hours. Can you post this as an answer, so that I can select it?

Comment: Posted -- glad it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your log file is going to the /bin folder, any file changes to this folder should recycle the application - killing your sessions.

Choosing a different folder on the server should resolve the issue.